# grails + selenium-rc plugin - cannot run sample test

Tags: grails, selenium

I have no idea what I do wrong. I would like to use selenium-RC plugin for Grails to do some functional testing. I have created sample test using build-in script (i guess add-selenium-test), which generated (i modified it slighty):

```
import grails.plugins.selenium.*
import org.junit.*
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*

@Mixin(SeleniumAware)
class FirstTestTests {
  @Before void setUp() {
  }

  @After void tearDown() {
    super.tearDown()
  }

  @Test void something() {
    selenium.open "/activate"
    assertTrue selenium.isTextPresent("activate")
  }
}
```

I configured SeleniumConfig

selenium {

```
  slow = false                                  // true to run tests in slow resources mode
  singleWindow = true                               // true for single window mode, false for multi-window mode
  browser = "*firefox"                          // can include full path to executable, default value is *firefox or *iexplore on Windows
  url = "http://localhost:8080"                                     // the base URL for tests, defaults to Grails server url
  defaultTimeout = 3000                         // the timeout after which selenium commands will fail
  windowMaximize = true                     // true to maximize browser on startup
  screenshot {
    dir = "./target/test-reports/screenshots"   // directory where screenshots are placed relative to project root
    onFail = true                           // true to capture screenshots on test failures
  }
  server {
    host = "localhost"                          // the host the selenium server will run on
    port = 4444                                 // the port the selenium server will run on
  }
  userExtensions = ""                               // path to user extensions javascript file

}
```

and I then I typed

```
  grails test-app :selenium
```

and it seems that everything is done correctly:

```
INFO 19:30:08,304 RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:
4444/wd/hub org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer
Starting Selenium server on port 4444 ...
INFO 19:30:08,312 Version Jetty/5.1.x org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer
INFO 19:30:08,315 Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/d
river] org.openqa.jetty.util.Container
INFO 19:30:08,318 Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server] org.ope
nqa.jetty.util.Container
INFO 19:30:08,321 Started HttpContext[/,/] org.openqa.jetty.util.Container
INFO 19:30:08,326 Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@55881a8f
 org.openqa.jetty.util.Container
INFO 19:30:08,328 Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd] org.openqa.jetty.util.Container
INFO 19:30:08,338 Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444 org.openqa.jetty.http.S
ocketListener
INFO 19:30:08,340 Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@42aefb01 org.openqa.jett
y.util.Container
Starting Selenium session for http://localhost:8080 ...
INFO 19:30:08,502 Checking Resource aliases org.openqa.jetty.util.Credential
INFO 19:30:08,510 Command request: getNewBrowserSession[*firefox, http://localho
st:8080, ] on session null org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHand
ler
INFO 19:30:08,512 creating new remote session org.openqa.selenium.server.Browser
SessionFactory
INFO 19:30:08,586 Allocated session 9250557308cc4886a25100eb6c5f3d7e for http://
localhost:8080, launching... org.openqa.selenium.server.BrowserSessionFactory
INFO 19:30:08,717 Preparing Firefox profile... org.openqa.selenium.server.browse
rlaunchers.FirefoxChromeLauncher
INFO 19:30:11,726 Launching Firefox... org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunche
rs.FirefoxChromeLauncher
```

The firefox window is opened, but nothing loads and nothing seems to proceed. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like an incompatibility between the Selenium RC plugin and the current version of your web browser. You might want to dig into the plugin's dependencies and update everything to the latest versions if you're using a newer version of the browser.

We see this with Geb ( http://www.gebish.org ) when trying to run a webdriver version that is not compatible with the driver version.

Comment: Thank you tomas for an idea - I will try to change the browser

Comment: you are the man! thanks, i changed to chrome and it worked 'out of the box' :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, if you use Chrome and your OS is Ubuntu, then make sure you put the full path to Chrome and make sure that the executable path references **chromium-browser** and **NOT** google-chrome.

So your SeleniumConfig should look like this with the relevant line in double asterisks:

```
selenium {

   slow = false
   singleWindow = true
   **browser = "*googlechrome /usr/bin/chromium-browser"**
   url = null
       defaultTimeout = 60000
   windowMaximize = false
   screenshot {
       dir = "./target/test-reports/screenshots"
       onFail = false
   }
   server {
       host = "localhost"
       port = 4444
   }
   userExtensions = ""
}
```

Comment: Update: this depends on your Linux distribution of chrome. If you have google-chrome, then it is known as google-chrome, else you have the Ubuntu packaged chrome in which case it is chromium-browser. See here for details http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome