# Grails - Selenium-RC plugin - Starting Selenium server

Tags: grails, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, functional-testing

I am trying to set up Selenium in my Grails project via the Selenium-RC plugin. 
I have then run the `grails install-plugin selenium-rc` command.

Then, I have run the `grails create-selenium-test firstTest` command, and added the following content to it:

```
import grails.plugins.selenium.*
import org.junit.*
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*

@Mixin(SeleniumAware)
class FirstTestTests {
    @Before void setUp() {
    }

    @After void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    @Test void something() {
        selenium.open "/"
        assertTrue selenium.isTextPresent("Bem vindos")
    }
}
```

When I run the test on Ubuntu 11.04, Grails starts the default firefox browser (version 8.0) but freezes here after printing this to the console output:

```
    Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/
  [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to /home/alessandro/Documents/[...]/target/test-classes/selenium
Starting Selenium server on port 4444 ...
Starting Selenium session for http://www.mywebsite.com/ ...
```

When I interrupt the test via Ctrl + C, it throws the following error message:

```
    Error running selenium tests: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not contact Selenium Server; have you started it on 'localhost:4444' ?
Read more at http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/not-started.html
Connection refused
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not contact Selenium Server; have you started it on 'localhost:4444' ?
Read more at http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/not-started.html
Connection refused
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:86)
        at com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium$start$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugins.selenium.SeleniumWrapper.start(SeleniumWrapper.groovy:90)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.plugins.selenium.SeleniumRunner.startSelenium(SeleniumRunner.groovy:35)
    at grails.plugins.selenium.SeleniumRunner$startSelenium.call(Unknown Source)
    at _Selenium_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_Selenium_groovy:50)
    at _Events$_run_closure3.doCall(_Events.groovy:32)
    at _GrailsEvents_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsEvents_groovy:58)
    at _GrailsEvents_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsEvents_groovy)
    at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure4.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:265)
    at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure4.call(_GrailsTest_groovy)
    at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:228)
    at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1_closure21.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:187)
    at _GrailsTest_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsTest_groovy:174)
    at TestApp$_run_closure1.doCall(TestApp.groovy:82)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
```

I have read the plugin doc, which says the server is started by the plugin, which is backed by the console output before the test freezes. I do not really know where to go from there. 
I have browse the web but the only piece advice I have found was to add the selenium-server.jar to java path, which seems to be covered by the plugin already.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue - you can see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369916/grails-selenium-rc-plugin-cannot-run-sample-test). the problem I guess is the firefox - I changed it to Chrome and it worked out of the box.
You just need to replace

```
  browser = "*firefox"
```

with

```
  browser = "*googlechrome"
```

in SeleniumConfig

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. It worked as you said. For those who uses Chromium as well under Ubuntu, here is what I added to configure the SeleniumConfig file:

```
browser = "*googlechrome /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser"
```

Now I get:

```
    Stopping Selenium server ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't start SslRelay: server is not started (perhaps it was just shut down?)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.ProxyHandler.getSslRelayOrCreateNew(ProxyHandler.java:656)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.ProxyHandler.handleConnect(ProxyHandler.java:589)
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.ProxyHandler.handle(ProxyHandler.java:274)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1530)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1482)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:909)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:245)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:357)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:534)
```

when after the test has passed. 
I'll investigate on it. **Thanks mkk**